# How to convert array of objects into array with changed positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects:

```
[
    { id: 'ade', value: 8 },
    { id: 'rtl', value: 17 },
    { id: 'enu', value: 11 }
]
```

and want to convert that to:

```
[
    { id: 'enu', value: 11 },
    { id: 'rtl', value: 17 },
    { id: 'ade', value: 8 },
]
```

but I can't reverse it etc, because I have to set a statement that item `{ id: 'ade', value: 8 }` should be last item and rest must be sorted by id.

I tried to reduce first array and concat with the second one

```
const firstArr = arr.reduce((acc, cv) => {
    if (cv.id === 'ade') {
        acc.push(cv)
    }
    return acc
}, []))

const second = arr.splice(firstArr, 1).sort()

firstArr.concat(second)
```

but it failed and seems over-engineering. I'd like to do it smarter. Any ideas?

Please about any advice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread operator to make the code look shorter,
But it's the same logic:

```
const arr = //...your array of data
const parsedArr = [...arr.filter(o => o.id !== 'ade').sort((a, b) => a.id.localeCompare(b.id)), ...arr.filter(o => o.id === 'ade')];
```

so the first part is all the array elements without the specific one that you need to be in the end, and the second part is the last element.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: But this will not sort the other objects by `id` property as required, it's just a coincidence that the output is matching the required output of the example array.

Comment: You're right, I added a use of the localCompare func for the sorting, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter, sort and then concatinate array with own rules:

```js
let orig = [
    { id: 'ade', value: 8 },
    { id: 'rtl', value: 17 },
    { id: 'enu', value: 11 }
]

sorted = orig.filter(e => e.id !== 'ade').sort((a, b) => 
   a.id.localeCompare(b.id)
).concat(orig.find(e => e.id === 'ade'))

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: That sort function does not produce the result required in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    { id: 'ade', value: 8 },
    { id: 'rtl', value: 17 },
    { id: 'enu', value: 11 },
].sort((a,b) => a.id == 'ade' ? 1 : b.id == 'ade' ? -1 : a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: It is not recommended to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes [**From Review**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29475455)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide custom logic in the callback passed to [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to handle elements whose `id === 'ade'` differently than other elements.

If either `id` equals "ade" return the difference of booleans, else compare the two ids using `localeCompare`.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 'ade', value: 8 },
  { id: 'rtl', value: 17 },
  { id: 'enu', value: 11 }
];

const sortedArr = [...arr].sort((a, b) => (
  (a.id === 'ade' || b.id === 'ade')
    ? (a.id === 'ade') - (b.id === 'ade')
    : a.id.localeCompare(b.id)));

console.log(sortedArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Example** – for `a = 'ade'` and `b = 'rtl'` the difference of the booleans returned by comparing them to `ade` returns `1` which sorts `b` before `a` and so pushes `ade` downward.

```
(('ade'==='ade') - ('rtl' === 'ade')) -> (true - false) -> (1 - 0) -> 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use`Array.prototype.localeCompare` for your case

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 'ade', value: 8 },
  { id: 'rtl', value: 17 },
  { id: 'enu', value: 11 }
]
arr.sort((a,b) => `${a.value}`.localeCompare(`${b.value}`))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score -1):

For this particular case you can use custom `sort` function:

```
const sortedArr = [...arr].sort((a, b) => {
    return b.id.localeCompare(a.id)
})
```

But if in the `arr` will be more objects you need to refactor sort function